# Which protocol use Virtualbox proxy?

Tags: virtualbox

I go to `File>Settings>Proxy` and see just two editboxes for IP and port of proxy. Which protocol will be used? `HTTP`, `SOCKS4`, `SOCKS5`? This isn't written anywhere.

Comment: I ask concretically question in captions and gave comprehensive information. If you dont understand something tall what exactly to clarify

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking about but see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VirtualBox manual](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/UserManual.pdf) says:

> The global settings dialog can be reached through the File menu,
>   selecting the Preferences...  item. It offers a selection of settings
>   which apply to all virtual machines of the current user or in the case
>   of Extensions to the entire system: (...)
>
> 8. Proxy Enables the user to configure a **HTTP Proxy Server**.